# How to make a simple TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been searching and trying stuff for like 4 hours and I can't get to make a simple TableView in iOS. Just like every app does..

Examples:

[image: Facebook example]

[image: Dropbox exampple]

I want to achieve something like dropbox does, just to have a login..

The last thing I tried and was the closest was to add a TableViewController, then a TableView inside it and then 2 TableViewCells inside it, but then when I add the elements in the Cells they just don't appear in the phone !!

Also I can't get to make a "padding" just like dropbox does, I think that maybe that is not a TableView, is it?

I am just a bit confused.. I watched 3 different videos but they are outdated, also the doc is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard change the `content` property of your table view from "dynamic prototype" to "Static cells"

Comment: Now it throws and error when I change to that view at
    `@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }` EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I finally solved it, I didn't know what was it really, but I crated a new clean Table View Controller because as I was trying lot of stuff, i really touched everything. I think the problem was that the Table View was not linked to the Controller or something like that, but your answer worked perfectly, thanks!